# Page finished loading, THEN do something with PHP code

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using a PHPMailer and I noticed that the email would be sent twice (duplicates). 1st is when the page almost finished loading (like 30-50% loading progress) and the 2nd is when the page is finished loading.
This has been a known issue for PHPMailer and Browser interaction and I'm trying to make my PHP page to only run once the page is actually finished loading.
How do I go about that?
The PHP Code is inside `<body>`

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                                
$mail->Host = $hostServer;                                      
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                        
$mail->Username = $senderEmail;                               
$mail->Password = $senderPassword;                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = $SMTP_SecureType;                        
$mail->Port = $SMTP_Port;                                    
$mail->setFrom($senderEmail, $senderName);                   
$mail->isHTML(true);                                          

    $mail->addAddress($appEmail);   
    $mail->Subject = "Subject here";
    $mail->Body = "Body here";
    $mail->AltBody = "Alt Body Here"; 
    if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        if ($debugMode == true) {
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        }
    }
```

Comment: How and when are you calling phpMailer and how are you outputting your html to the broswer? echo or outside of php tags?

Comment: My script will be ran from another page, for example, Page A to Page B (where Page A sends information to Page B, and Page B will process the information to send as email content). wait, I'll edit the main post.

Comment: Check your submitted data each time; I would expect there may be a difference. There isn't a PHPMailer issue with browser interaction at all - there is an issue with some browser plugins issuing repeat requests, but that's nothing to do with anything in PHP.